# What is the format name to have a MP4 video as output in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, mencoder

The following command

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -f ogg - > video.mp4
```

Does not produce a `.mp4` video.

I want to replace `-f ogg` with `-f <mp4 format>` where `<mp4 format>` is the right format to generate a video in `.mp4`.

To make thinks clear, I want to have:

```
# file video.mp4
video.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
```

---

PS: I want to use pipe, since it is used for other pipe operations

Comment: @Thomas I mistakenly voted against your edit, didn't notice you fixed the code-formatting. Sorry about that! As long as a third person shows up and votes for it, though, it'll be approved anyway. Just want to leave an explanation in case the site mentions the no vote...

Answer (score 3):

`ffmpeg -formats` will list all of them, its sounds like you're looking for (surprisingly enough) `-f mp4`.

Note that depending on your V4L capture device's format, you may need to specify encoding to an MPEG-4 compatible audio (`-codec:a` / `-acodec`) and video codec (`-codec:v` / `-vcodec`).

Comment: Thanks. Can you however briefly explain how the right codec is found?

Comment: @j1088099.mvrht.com. There aren't really *correct* ones, some are not supported inside MP4 (and similarly other container formats only support certain codecs). But probably you want H.264 (`-c:v libx264`) and one of several audio codecs; https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio has a list (by container format).